# HazelcastSerializationException with Hazelcast 4.2 and bucket4j 6.2.0

Tags: hazelcast

I have upgraded my Hazelcast and bucket 4j. And now I have  error
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.bucket4j.grid.CommandResult

What is strange - this error happens only when I run my application on Kubernetes. When I run it on virtual machine or on my latop everything works OK

My application is using Spring Boot 2.2.1 and Spring Cloud Gateway and react

What I am doing wrong ?

My gradle dependencies

```
  implementation "com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov:bucket4j-core:6.2.0"
   implementation "com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov:bucket4j-jcache:6.2.0"
   implementation "com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov:bucket4j-hazelcast:6.2.0"
   implementation "javax.cache:cache-api:1.0.0"
   implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast:4.2"
   implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-eureka-one:2.0.1"
```

My Hazelcast configuration code

````
 ```
    Config config = new Config();
   config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getEurekaConfig().setEnabled(false);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(false);

        if (eurekaClientOption.isPresent()) {
            EurekaClient eurekaClient = eurekaClientOption.get();
            String appName = eurekaClient.getApplicationInfoManager().getEurekaInstanceConfig().getAppname();
            logger.info("hazelcast appName :" + appName);
            Application application = eurekaClient.getApplication(appName);
            if (application != null) {
                application.getInstancesAsIsFromEureka().forEach(
                        instanceInfo -> {
                            config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember(instanceInfo.getIPAddr() + ":" + port);
                            logger.info("hazelcast TcpIpConfig : {}",config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig());
                        }
                );
            } else {
                logger.error("hazelcast empty eureka application [{}]",appName);
            }
        } else {
            logger.error("hazelcast empty eurekaClient");
        }
        config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(port).setPortAutoIncrement(false);
        config.setLiteMember(false);
        logger.info("hazelcast config {}",config);
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.phone.home.enabled", "false");
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size","1");
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.socket.server.bind.any", "false");
   HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = new HazelcastInstanceFactory(config).getHazelcastInstance();
````

````
My bucket4j code

    ```
    if (hazelcastInstance != null) {
            IMap map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("bucket");
            int initialCapacity = (throttlingRule.getBandwith() + throttlingRule.getOverdraftBandwith());
            this.bucket = Bucket4j.extension(Hazelcast.class)
                    .builder()
                    .addLimit(Bandwidth.classic(initialCapacity, Refill.smooth(throttlingRule.getBandwith(), Duration.of(throttlingRule.getDuration(), throttlingRule.getDurationUnit()))))
                    .build(map, key, RecoveryStrategy.RECONSTRUCT);

            VerboseResult<EstimationProbe> verboseResult = bucket.asVerbose().estimateAbilityToConsume(1);
            BucketConfiguration bucketConfiguration = verboseResult.getConfiguration();
            logger.info("bucket for rule [{}] and key [{}] configuration [{}] availableTokens [{}]",throttlingRule,key,bucketConfiguration,bucket.getAvailableTokens());
        } else  {
            logger.warn("hazelcastInstance == null");
        }
````

```
  public ConsumptionProbe throttleProbe() {
       assert bucket != null;
       CompletableFuture<ConsumptionProbe> probe = bucket.asAsync().tryConsumeAndReturnRemaining(1);
       return probe.join();
   }
```

Exception

```
j.l.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.bucket4j.grid.CommandResult
    at j.i.l.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at j.i.l.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at j.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at c.h.i.n.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:289)
    at c.h.i.n.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:249)
    at c.h.i.n.IOUtil$ClassLoaderAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:910)
    at j.i.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1995)
    at j.i.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
    at j.i.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at j.i.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at j.i.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
    at j.i.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
    at c.h.i.s.i.d.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:86)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: c.h.n.s.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.bucket4j.grid.CommandResult
    at c.h.i.s.i.d.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:90)
    at c.h.i.s.i.d.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:79)
    at c.h.i.s.i.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
    at c.h.i.s.i.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:208)
    at c.h.s.i.DelegatingCompletableFuture$DeserializingFunction.apply(DelegatingCompletableFuture.java:518)
    at c.h.s.i.AbstractInvocationFuture.lambda$unblockCompose$5(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:953)
    at j.u.c.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
    at j.u.c.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at j.u.c.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at j.u.c.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at j.u.c.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at j.u.c.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Wrapped by: j.u.c.CompletionException: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.bucket4j.grid.CommandResult
    at j.u.c.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
    at j.u.c.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346)
    at j.u.c.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:632)
    at j.u.c.CompletableFuture.unipush(CompletableFuture.java:589)
    at j.u.c.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:660)
    at j.u.c.CompletableFuture.thenApplyAsync(CompletableFuture.java:2104)
    at c.h.s.i.InternalCompletableFuture.thenApply(InternalCompletableFuture.java:78)
    at i.g.b.AbstractBucket$1.tryConsumeAndReturnRemaining(AbstractBucket.java:147)
    at p.b.g.t.ThrottlingRuleBucket.throttleProbe(ThrottlingRuleBucket.java:64)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I run my application on Kubernetes"? In the above code, I see nothing related to containerization nor to deployment. It depends a lot on both.

Comment: Yes, of course, it is a pure Java code. This application is then dockerized, and created docker image is deployed on K8S cluster. Why do you think, that it depends on conterization or deployment ?

Comment: Anyway , when I have changed from
`CompletableFuture<ConsumptionProbe> probe = bucket.asAsync().tryConsumeAndReturnRemaining(1);`
to
`CompletableFuture<ConsumptionProbe> probe = bucket.tryConsumeAndReturnRemaining(1);`
error disappeared

Answer (score 1):

@Jacuo I was facing the same issue where my application on my laptop was working fine but from within Docker container it was failing with `HazelcastSerializationException`.

I found out that the issue was not with Serialization on Hazelcast member side but in fact issue was on client side. Following change fixed the issue for me.

```
new ClientConfig()
     .setClassLoader(CommandResult.class.getClassLoader())  <------ THIS LINE HERE
     .setClusterName(clusterName)
     .setInstanceName(String.format("%s-%s", clusterName, UUID.randomUUID()))
     .setUserCodeDeploymentConfig(userCodeDeploymentConfig)
     .setNetworkConfig(networkConfig);
```

For more information see https://github.com/vladimir-bukhtoyarov/bucket4j/issues/162#issuecomment-966890797

Answer (score 0):

The classes need to be present in the cluster members. Can you confirm that the dependencies you mention included in your deployment? If they are not on the member image, you can configure user-code-deployment (https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/clusters/deploying-code-on-member.html) to allow a member to load classes from a client.

Comment: Yes, I am sure - without it, my code doesn`t compile :-)

Comment: @Jacuo I think you misunderstand. Yes, your code can compile and fail at runtime because the code is not on the member's classpath. Tom's question is perfectly legitimate and you don't answer it. Also, please refrain from answering "of course", as if everything was clear because it's not and we're trying to help you.

Comment: @Nicolas - Sorry, I didn`t mension it in my question, but I don`t have a separate cluster, It is formed by Java applications when they run ( this application, which is also a client ). Anyway problem didn`t exist with previous versions of Hazelcast and bucket4j. 
As for answwering "of course" - maybe in english it sounds offensive, but not in my native language, sorry.